# Specifying timeout option with setsockopt() results in subsequent listen error

Tags: c++, linux, setsockopt

Right now, I am trying to specify options with `setsockopt()` using the following code:

```
// bind socket
// Use setsockopt() function to make sure the port is not in use
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(TCPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(TCPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
status = bind(TCPSocket, host_info_list->ai_addr, host_info_list->ai_addrlen);
if (status == -1)  std::cout << "bind error" << std::endl ;

// listen for connections
status =  listen(TCPSocket, 5);
if (status == -1)  std::cout << "listen error" << std::endl ;

int new_sd;
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
new_sd = accept(TCPSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);
if (new_sd == -1) std::cout << "listen error" << std::endl ;
```

Note `tv` is an already-specified timeval.

When I make only the first `setsockopt()` call, everything works fine. However, with the addition of the second (which does not return any errors), I encounter the second "listen error" specified in the code. I'm not sure why setting the timeout value affect this, can someone explain?

I do not take credit for the code specified; it is modified from the code presented in the tutorial here: http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return any errors (the second call) ? you don't do any return value check or `errno` access?  By the way, what do you think `SO_RCVTIMEO` does?  What do you expect to set in the second call? perhaps your idea of that parameter is not the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see a TCP state diagram [like this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram.png) you see there's a state called `TIME_WAIT` when actively closing a socket. This state can take some time before it ends, up to four minutes according to [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793).

While the socket is in the `TIME_WAIT` you can not bind to an interface using the same address-port pair as the socket that is in the wait state. Setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag om a socket enables other sockets to bind to the address when the current socket (with the flag set) is in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

The `SO_REUSEADDR` option is most useful for server (passive, listening) sockets.

---

As for your problem, after each call to [`setsockopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) check what it returns, and if it's `-1` then you check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what went wrong. You can use [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to print or get a printable string for the error, like

```
if (setsockopt(TCPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Error setting the SO_REUSEADDR: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
    // Do something appropriate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand why that option is necessary (I am using that port with each subsequent run of my program!). I tried your suggestion and do not encounter any errors, but get an error later in the program (note there are no errors when not specifying the timeout options). I will edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim's solution did a great job of answering my intial question and explaining setsockopt(). To answer my own question after realizing the issue was further down in the code, the timeout affects the server being able to listen to a port. Say the timeout is only 10ms, the server must be started, then the client, and a connection must be established in that time. This wasn't happening in my case, thus the resulting error.